# "NullPointerException: null cannot be cast to non null type Error" in kotlin

Tags: android, arrays, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, nullpointerexception

```
 var notify = ArrayList<String>()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_user)
        btn_list2.setOnClickListener {

            val sharedPreferences1 = getSharedPreferences("id", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
            val documentid: String? = sharedPreferences1.getString("id","null")
            val c = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
            val d = c.collection("applicationForm").document(documentid.toString()).get()
                .addOnSuccessListener { document ->

                    notify = document?.get("notifyTo") as ArrayList<String>

                    var str1 = notify.joinToString()
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext,str1,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

}}}
```

Here I get error in the line `notify = document?.get("notifyTo") as ArrayList<String>`.

This is my logcat details

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null cannot be cast to non-null type java.util.ArrayList<kotlin.String>
        at com.example.bloodbankcompany.MainActivityUser.onCreate$lambda-4$lambda-3(MainActivityUser.kt:47)
        at com.example.bloodbankcompany.MainActivityUser.lambda$cGlrfLFSOO25IeEAacXMuz6Tzx0(Unknown Source:0)`.
```

Please can anyone help. Here I am trying to read a array document from firestore.

Comment: either your `document` is null or it does not contain a `notifyTo` field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correctly gating `document?.get(...)` but you are casting the result to an ArrayList.

Since either `document` is null OR there is no `"notifyTo"` key in your document result, you end up basically doing `null as ArrayList<String>`. Hence the error.

To stop getting the crash, you need to do `document.get("notifyTo") as? ArrayList<String>`

But really want you want to make sure of is that "notifyTo" exists inside your document so that you no longer get a null return value

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `.addOnSuccessListener` returns the result, not the value so it will obviously cause an exception.

```
    var documents: ArrayList<String> = arrayListOf()

    c.collection("applicationForm").document(documentid.toString()).get()
                .addOnSuccessListener { result ->
                documents = result.value
    }
```

**also check if result.values is != null**,
get the value like this, also at the end check if you are mapping the collection correctly.